# How to use Bootstrap 3 grid if elements are tiled with different height and widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) for a couple of projects recently and love the way how simple it can work. Nevertheless I now have some questions where I don't really know how to use it. If I'm having a few divs which are tiled, I'm wondering how the best way would be to change the order, or the position within the grid on different breakpoints. I made a simple visualisation to explain my problem:

[image]

On the left hand side, you see the state on large desktops, and on the right hand side how it should look like on the next smaller breakpoint. The problems I currently have are: How would I handle the `blue` div on `.row1`, to have the `red` div on `.row2` next to it on the right in a new row. 
And on the breakpoints, would it be possible for the red div, to move to another row?

I'm searching for a Bootstrap/CSS only way, but if it is definitely not working without JS/jQuery, I would appreciate those suggestions too.

Hope you get my point. Thanks!

**Edit:** Related image to my other question in @Danko 's answer, which was how to switch tiles on different breakpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to manage the same logic but don't slice your desgin in two rows, just one:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 B"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 G"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 O"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this **[DemoBootply](http://www.bootply.com/kmqk8tgYvF)**

Comment: alright, that seem to work. So Bootstrap simply goes with the markup order and automatically floats the elements as wanted? Because what if I want the blue div wanted to be small and on the right side on the right picture in the `md` state? That it basically switchtes the position with the green ones. Is that somehow possibly with the default like in the left picture?

Comment: @supersize bootstrap have some options you can trick and use based on the look you want like this http://www.bootply.com/glibuzMCbl ... Just need to know how use that on specifica cases. This answer works as well you want.

Comment: Bootstrap is a beast! Awesome! Do you have the link to the docs of `push` and `pull` classes you applied? I have never heard about it.

Comment: I completely haven't seen this while going through the docs. Thank you sir!