# Bootstrap 3 pull and push not behaving as intend

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a question for [Bootstrap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7qwZ.png) pull and push column ordering. I made a simple image to explain my problem. On the left side is the `lg` and `md` version of my grid. On the right hand side, how it should look like in `sm`.

[image]

after finding out (thanks to @Danko) that Bootstrap has `push` and `pull` options I did following:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-8"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8"></div>
```

But I can't get it to work. First of all, all columns are shifted weird on all other breakpoints than `sm` but also on `sm` one of the green boxes disappear.

Did I get something wrong with the logic of pull and push? Really need some help!

Comment: The `push` and `pull` classes are hereditary, so col-sm-push-8 will affect the div's class in `md` and `lg` as well. If you want the classes to apply only in sm, you need to add `col-md-push-0` or `col-md-pull-0`. Doesn't solve you problem but explains why it looks messy in other sizes than sm!

Comment: @NicoFerna thank you for making that clearer!

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no way to get what you want with push/pull unless you create custom media queries. A better way may be to use the Bootstrap utility classes to create 2 separate versions of your markup. 1 for `md`/`lg` and 1 for `xs`/`sm`

```
<div class="row hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm">
   <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-6"> </div>    
   <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/876ukbaHyW

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is a good approach but I would like to refer to this question from me, where I didn't know that column ordering existed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765464/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-grid-if-elements-are-tiled-with-different-height-and-widt inside there is a http://www.bootply.com/glibuzMCbl where this is working fine, or do I oversee something?

Comment: Can you please come-up with the solution that does not hide the columns / divs?

Comment: As I said, the solution requires custom media queries.

Comment: @supersize - the other example is different. The blue cell in your example moves down to the bottom row. If you don't mind moving the blue cell down and keeping the green above it's easier like this.. http://www.bootply.com/y9N6cXjYSQ

Comment: @Skelly thanks for your answer. I definitely want to have the blue box as on the image above. What would be the custom media queries solution look like?

Answer (score -1):

This question may be old but I found a solution using visible and hidden instead of using push and pull because it could not be done unless custom media queries as mentioned by Skelly and I have also used some of the codes from Skelly

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 O"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 visible-md visible-lg B"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 G"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 G"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 hidden-md hidden-lg B"></div>
</div>
```

Used back Skelly's bootply [bootply.com/y9N6cXjYSQ](http://bootply.com/y9N6cXjYSQ) and replace this code with the existing one.